# How to Use XPath Loop Inside a Ruby Loop

Tags: ruby, xpath

I'm trying to find elements in a document for removal. I am able to manually build a query using something like this:

```rb
article.xpath("//*[@*[contains(., 'popular')]]", "//*[@*[contains(., 'comments')]]", "//*[@*[contains(., 'social-share')]]").each do |node|
  node.remove
end
```

Using a variable is also working:

```rb
line = 'related'
article.xpath("//*[@*[contains(., '#{line}')]]").each do |node|
  node.remove
end
```

I'd like to add all the words to a separate file and loop that file. I've tried the following but it is not working (silent failure—no output).

```rb
file = 'stop_words.txt'
File.readlines(file).each do |line|
  article.xpath("//*[@*[contains(., '#{line}')]]").each do |node|
    node.remove
  end
end
```

The `File.readlines(file).each` loop is working fine. If I add `puts line`, it prints the list from stop_words.txt. Why is the `article.xpath` loop not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each "word" in your file includes a newline at the end:

```sh
$ rm ~/test

$ printf "foo\nbar\nbaz" > ~/test

$ cat ~/test
foo
bar
baz
```

Now read it with Ruby:

```rb
words = File.readlines("#{Dir.home}/test")
=> ["foo\n", "bar\n", "baz"]
```

Note that the words have newlines, so when you do this:

```rb
article.xpath("//*[@*[contains(., '#{line}')]]")
```

You're really doing:

```rb
article.xpath("//*[@*[contains(., 'foo\n')]]")
```

Your best bet is to use `chomp: true` with `.readlines`:

```rb
words = File.readlines("#{Dir.home}/test", chomp: true)
=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Whether or not this actually solves the underlying problem, I can't say. But I can tell you for certain that this is a bug in your code that has to be resolved.

Comment: This did indeed solve the problem. I didn't think `.readlines` was reading the `\n`. Cheers.